# Couple of issues with project based on Play framework 2.5.0 version

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am learning play framework 2.5.0 and have made one java project using that. I am facing couple of issues in it which I am unsure how to resolve it.

Following are my issues:
a) I am getting below when I clean and compile code, where exactly can I specify the right version so that these warnings can go away:

```
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.typesafe.play:play-netty-server_2.11:2.4.0 -> 2.5.0
[warn]  * com.typesafe.play:play-java_2.11:2.4.0 -> 2.5.0
[warn]  * com.typesafe.play:play-server_2.11:2.4.0 -> 2.5.0
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
```

Build.sbt looks like:

```
 name := "test-application"
 version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
 scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
 lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb)
 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     javaJpa,javaJdbc,
     "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.9.Final",
     "ojdbc14" % "ojdbc14" % "1.0",
     "org.scala-lang" % "scala-dist" % "2.11.7"
 ) 
resolvers += "sonatype snapshots" at   
   "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)
EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java
EclipseKeys.createSrc :=     
EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses,   
EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources)

PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false
fork in run := true
```

Build.properties look like:

```
template.uuid=24cd0d2e-3a06-42f1-91c8-62655e1eb7d7
sbt.version=0.13.11
```

Plugins.sbt look like:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.github.ddispaltro" % "sbt-reactjs" % "0.5.2")
```

b) I also get warning as below, what exactly can I do to fix this:

```
..\views\main.scala.html:6: method current in object Play is deprecated: This is a static reference to application, use DI instead
     <title>@current.configuration.getString("reports")</title>
```

c) I have recently upgraded from 2.4 to 2.5 & since then when I compile and deploy, am getting error as below, which jar am I missing here? Do I need to explicitly add its dependency?

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lplay/libs/F$Predicate;
```

I have noticed that  play 2.4.6 has F$Predicate class but 2.5.0 doesn't have it.
Actually, none of the 2.5.x version has F$Predicate class in it library.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play_2.11" % "2.4.6"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play_2.11" % "2.5.0"
```

If I have upgraded to 2.5.0 then what is it which is internally referring to F$Predicate class?

Comment: It's not a solution, just point - switch to the 2.5.0, it's already released, you do not need to use 2.5.0-RC1 now.

Comment: Thanks @AndriyKuba, point taken so have made change and have updated details in this ticket accordingly.

Comment: actually, I think that in the "a" you have an old version of some sbt plugins or libraries. Try to review them, maybe there is new versions, specially built fro the Play 2.5, for example, "sbt-play-ebean" had change to 3.0.0

Comment: I understand that, but the point is I have no where specified anything for netty-server, play-java & play-server. That's why am not sure where I need to make a change to upgrade, on top of it with which version.

Comment: What about sbt and scala version ? did you rose up them as well? sbt must be 0.13.9 and scala 2.11.7

Comment: Yes, I am using scalaVersion := "2.11.7" in builds.sbt & sbt.version=0.13.11 in build.properties in project folder.

Comment: Would be nice if you will add your build.sbt file to the question. Or just test it yourself by switching off libraries. And I am pretty sure that putting 3 different question in one is not an optimal strategy to receive an answer.

Comment: @AndriyKuba: I have put build.[sbt/properties] code in description.

Comment: I have no warning with this build (of course I did not test  "ojdbc14" % "ojdbc14" % "1.0" - it looks like your local).  What about plugins.sbt? Could you add it as well?

Comment: @AndriyKuba: Added code for pluging.sbt as well

Comment: I do not see the warning with this either. Maybe someone else saw something similar.

Comment: To make the warnings about deprecation (Play.current) go away, you will have to switch to dependency injection. With that, you can inject an instance of the play configuration into your controller and then use that in the view template. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDependencyInjection

Comment: @rethab: Thanks for helping. Actually, I have gone through this link before as well, but this doesn't explain how we can inject dependency in views. In my case I have main.scala.html file wherein I am importing current instance as import play.api.Play.current and then using it as current.configuration.getString("testapp"). Can you suggest an approach how dependency can be injected in views. Thanks !!

Comment: It's not possible (primarily for technical reasons, but I doubt this would be nice from an architectual/structual perspective). You better inject it in the controller and then pass it to the view as parameter.